# Webform send emails based on selection criteria

Tags: webforms, emails

I am attempting to create a sort of booking / quote form using Webform.

I have 2 taxonomy selection criteria "Location" and "Service", I am trying to get the form to send emails to the users that have nodes in both the matching criteria.

For example, if the selection was Perth, Western Australia and Electrician, I would like the form to send an email to all the users who have nodes created in that criteria.

Hopefully this makes sense, and hopefully it's possible!

I looked at the Rules module; obviously I would use *After a webform has been submitted* as action. I wonder which actions would help. If I use *Send mail to user* would adding the *Content has term* as condition help in sending the form details to the correct user(s)?